# New IE8 CSS file with Heroku Rails App

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error on Heroku when attempting to add a new CSS file for IE8.

I've added the file, titled ie8.css, to `app/assets/stylesheets`

And then in `application.html.erb` I've added the following the the `<head>`:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag "ie8" %><![endif]-->
```

Seems so simple, but I can't figure out my problem. Any recommendations on how I can solve this bug? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error? Did you compile your assets?

Comment: Did you precompile your assets?

Comment: Ahh! Nope, I did not precompile. That was my problem. Thanks!